# should I delete a question which answer is a configuration error?

Tags: discussion

I was having [trouble with elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863179/elasticsearch-server-status-503-discovery-fails). I did extensive research documented in the question and my initial thoughts pointed towards a bug.

It turns out that it was a simple (and stupid) configuration issue (not even that, I simply forgot one piece of the configuration string...)

**Should such question be deleted?** I feel that the usefulness for someone is close to zero (as the issue is purely my fault, it is not like there was something wrong in the docs or defaults) and the probability for someone to have the same problem is very, very small.

I would like to avoid leaving trash behind or giving someone false hope about a solution if he happens to have the issue described in the question (but coming from somewhere else)

Comment: *I would like to avoid leaving trash behind or giving someone false hope about a solution if he happens to have the issue described in the question (but coming from somewhere else)* I'd rather try something and find out it doesn't work than not try it when it would work. I had a silly issue with an application the other day where `Paste` didn't work and found the answer 3 days later after I got tired of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel that the question wouldn't be of use to anyone else, you can simply delete it, yes.

If the question cannot be deleted (due to an answer with a positive score) then you could vote to close the question for the following reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Thanks. I answered it myself and accepted the answer - so I will go for the   flag.